# create a border effect around element when there is a pseudo element covering or hiding part of the element

Tags: html, css

I have an angled cornered tab whose angles were create by using `:after` and `:before`. I would like to get a border around the tabs. Obviously if i just do `border: 1px solid ;` for the `li` it will create a box around the tab and not around the shape. How would you get it done? here's what I was working with.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: .4em .9em;
  position: relative;
}
li:before, li:after{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  /*left: 0;*/
  content: "";
}
li:before{
  left: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid white;
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
li:after{
  right: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
li:first-of-type{
  padding-top: .5em;
}

.area{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  /*margin: 0;*/
  padding: 0;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>tab1</li> <li>tab two</li>
</ul>
<div class="area">DIVS</div>
```

Comment: maybe help this answer: [making-borders-around-css-shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960993/making-borders-around-css-shapes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use squares instead of triangles and rotate them:

```
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: .4em .9em;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li:before, li:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size:0;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
li:before{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
li:after{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/doqopugomu/1/edit?html,css,output).